# User menu in community builder is not working

Tags: community, community-builder, lightning-community

I want to configure user menu with only my profile,my settings and Logout options in my community(Customer Service template), it is working while seeing using preview in builder but when I tried to login as community user it is just removing the label and empty space is still showing in menu setting please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this you can use a css change in the Community Builder, in the Theme and selecting Edit CSS.

If you add the following it will hide the My profile and My Account in the user menu.

```
.profile.uiMenuItem{
    display: none;
}

.myAccount{
    display: none; 
    }
```